# Regex help required

Tags: jquery, regex, string-parsing

I am using following regex to convert digits into phone format.

```
telephoneNumber = '1234567890';
var number = telephoneNumber.replace(/\D/g,''); 
newNumber = number.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/, '($1)$2-$3'); // (123)456-7890
```

**Problem** is that if telephoneNumber.length is greater than 10 then it does nothing. I want to add extra digits in the end of the phone number.

For example:

```
change 1234567890 to (123)456-7890
change 1234567890111 to (123)456-7890111
```

What should I change in above regex.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the last line to this:
`newNumber = number.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4,})$/, '($1)$2-$3');`

I just added a comma after the `\d{4` this tells it to take 4 or more digits.

Also, I often use this site to test out my regex's: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ It's VERY handy.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can see you wanting to use a Regex is for validation, however if you're just trying to format the string to a phone number, why not just use a [Javascript Phone Number Formatter](http://javascript.internet.com/forms/format-phone-number.html)

Comment: copy it, drop it in a scripts directory, and use it over and over. Regex is (IMO) a last resort.